# What is the difference between .env.local and .env.development.local?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I used a `create-react-app`.

And created environment variable files. `.env.local`, `.env.development.local`

I found that `.env.development` ispreferred over `.env.local`

And `env.development.local` seems to have prioty over `.env.development`.

If so, `.env.development.local` is used to override `.env.development` what is the purpose of `.env.local`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In `.env.local` you can set up environment variables that are specific to your local machine and it doesn't have to be on development mode to work, so variables there will work for both `development` and `production`.

Comment: how do i load .env.local with require('dotenv')?

Comment: @chovy tbh i prefer `dotenv-flow`, then just `require('dotenv-flow').config(); const url = process.env.DB;`

Comment: @chovy I don't think there's a concept of override in `dotenv` as specified by [this issue](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/199). But if you just want to load `.env.local` from `dotenv` then you can pass it in config as mentioned [here](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path).

Answer (score 151):

Here's the priority of the files for the development build and the production build:

**Dev.:** (`npm start`): `.env.development.local`, **`.env.local`**, `.env.development`, `.env`

**Prod.:** (`npm run build`): `.env.production.local`, **`.env.local`**, `.env.production`, `.env`

If you ever want to use something in your local environment without being specific to the development build or the production build, you can add some variables to your `.env.local` file.

Source : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Comment: How does that read? Is the top priority file on the right or on the left?

Comment: @PaulinTrognon Top priority is on the left.

Comment: Could you please kindly provide the source of the answer?

Comment: How do you exclude .env.local from the Prod chain?

Comment: .env.production.local  More specific tends to be higher priority.

Comment: for some reasons .env.local does not work when there is a .env.development, but .env.development.local does work