# How does a Vite Vue project handle environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, vuejs3, vite, dotenv

I have a Vue project built with Vite, and I need to have at least 3 different `environment` files.

I have:

- `.env.local`
- `.env.development`
- `.env.production`

As far as I know, when running `npm run build` (alias for `vite build` in my project) the build process should pick up the `.env.production` shouldn't it?. However I'm noticing that it always picks up the `.env.local` file.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55690323/8437694) explaining the priorities of the environment files, but does it mean that if there's an `.env.local` file in the project it will always pick that one unless explicitly stating the mode? (e.g: `vite build --mode production`)? Or am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a way to make sure running `vite build` picks up the `production` file?

Answer (score 1):

The [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) explain the same priority based loading.

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

> An env file for a specific mode (e.g. `.env.production`) will take higher priority than a generic one (e.g. `.env`).

`build` command runs in production mode by default.

If you want to override `.env.local` you can put variables in `.env.production.local` which should take priority.

`.env.production` can't override `.env.local` but `.env.development.local` sounds more appropriate for local variables if they're not meant for production.